# Custom UILabel and display attributes on Interface Builder Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift

I created a custom `UILabel` and defined some styles. It only displayed the attributes on Interface Builder. Nothing changed when I built. What am I missing here?

```
@objc public enum CustomLabelStyle: Int {
    case ScreenTitle = 0
    case H2 = 1
    case H3 = 2
    case BodyText = 3
    case BodyTextGray = 4
    case DescriptionText = 5
}

@IBDesignable class JWLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable open var style: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            customStyle(style: style)
        }
    }

    func customStyle(style: Int){
        var font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
        var color = UIColor(hexString: "#8E8E8E")
        var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3

        switch style {
        case CustomLabelStyle.ScreenTitle.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.H2.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.H3.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 4
        case CustomLabelStyle.BodyText.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 13)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.BodyTextGray.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 13)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#8E8E8E")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.DescriptionText.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#8E8E8E")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        let attribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : font,
                         NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : color,
                         NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle]
        self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "", attributes: attribute)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should set your custom style when you change the text. Right now this custom style is applied to the text when UILabel is initialized and first `didSet` for `style` is called. At that point of time, text is empty so it shows in nothing. When you set your text, it gets no styling.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `customStyle` method call before the set text on a label. so the change is the call of the `customStyle` method.

```
@IBDesignable class JWLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable open var style: Int = 0

    func customStyle(style: Int){
        var font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
        var color = UIColor(hexString: "#8E8E8E")
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3

        switch style {
        case CustomLabelStyle.ScreenTitle.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.H2.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.H3.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 4
        case CustomLabelStyle.BodyText.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 13)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#404040")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.BodyTextGray.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 13)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#8E8E8E")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 3
            break
        case CustomLabelStyle.DescriptionText.rawValue:
            font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
            color = UIColor(hexString: "#8E8E8E")
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        let attribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : font,
                         NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : color,
                         NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle]
        self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "", attributes: attribute)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.customStyle(style: style)
    }
}

//Set text on a label
    lblTest.text = "This is the dummy text for test"
```

Comment: I have a question. I do function `customStyle` in `layoutSubviews` and `didSet` of instance for IB rendering. Is it a bad performance ?